# Connecting my Toshiba L655 Laptop to LCD TV with only VGA?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, lcd, vga, toshiba-laptop

I read through the specs and looked at my laptop. I dont think it has a HDMI port.
So I guess I am left with VGA port to connect to LCD TV.

I need to know is it possible to connect my laptop to HDMI port of LCD (any external device I need to buy) or if I connect it via VGA port, how much resolution I can expect and which cable I need to buy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VJ9RCO) will do the trick. The maximum resolution supported by this device is 1280x768.

You may have to supply your own VGA and HDMI cables, which are cheap on [Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com).

Comment: and which cable I need to use if I want directly connect to the TV using VGA port on laptop? and what will be the maximum resolution in that case?

Comment: You will need an [HDMI cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10240&cs_id=1024004&p_id=3661&seq=1&format=2) that goes from the TV to the converter box, and a [Male-Male VGA cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10201&cs_id=1020101&p_id=3622&seq=1&format=2) to go from the converter box to the laptop. You don't really have to buy these cables at Monoprice, but I use them because they are cheap and well made. The maximum resolution is determined by the converter box, which will be 1280x768.

Comment: @Jags Did this solution work for you?

Comment: I dont want to spend on that box. Do you know whats the resolution I will get with a VGA cable?

Comment: @Jags 1920x1080 is the maximum resolution for a 1080p HDTV. The maximum resolution you'll get over the VGA port on your laptop depends on the graphics adapter in the laptop. Most laptops (aside from some Atom-based netbooks) made in the last 3 years should be able to support the maximum resolution of your TV.

Comment: ok..so VGA will output whatever the max resolution I can see on my laptop..my LCD is HDTV..although I will have to check whats the max HD resolution it supports. But I guess VGA should be good enough for now..thanks for the info @Trav